# Colours in Windows cmd with Python

Tags: python, cmd, colors

I am trying to get colours to work in Python using windows cmd but it is not working. I've tried a few packages, but they all result in something similar.

At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
from colors import *

print(color('some text', fg='rgb(255, 0, 0)'))
```

However, this just prints [38;2;255;0;0msome text[0m into the console in white.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I am using [this package](https://pypi.org/project/ansicolors/).

EDIT2: I need to print many different exact RGB values.

EDIT3: The below code works for colorama, but afaik colorama doesn't allow you to specify exact RGB values.

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

init(convert=True)

print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
```

Answer (score 1):

[Re-enable ANSI console color for Windows 10.16257 and later](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/15758): run

```
reg add HKCU\Console /v VirtualTerminalLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Restart Windows command prompt (`cmd.exe`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `os.system('')` before `print(color('some text', fg='rgb(255, 0, 0)'))` *Remember to import* **os*** module using*`import os`.

Like,

```
os.system('')
print(color('some text', fg='rgb(255, 0, 0)'))
```